# How to get data for star-rating from database in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The values do not pass for "rate_number" from database."ratingValue" alert and "id" alert are working, but "num" alert is not working.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where genre='$genre' limit 0,5");

if($jrowa['rate_number'] > 0){ 
   $ratea = $jrowa['rate_score'] / $jrowa['rate_number']; 
   $rateid = $jrowa['id'];
}else{ 
   $ratea = 0; 
   $rateid = $jrowa['id'];
}
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 portfolio-item" style="width: 20%;">

    <input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" id="<?php echo $rateid; ?>" name="rating" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;"/>

</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
          var $stars = $('.input-star-rate');

          $stars.bind('change', function() {
             var $this = $(this); 
             var ratingValue = $this.val();
             alert(ratingValue);

             var id = $this.attr("id");
             alert(id);

             var num = parseInt($this.attr("rate_number") + 1, 10);
             alert(num);
          });
      });
 });
```

Comment: is `$ratea` your rated ratio??

Comment: Your `<input>` doesn't have a `rate_number` attribute, so why are you trying to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 var num = parseInt($this.attr("value") + 1, 10);
             alert(num);
```

instead of

```
 var num = parseInt($this.attr("rate_number") + 1, 10);
             alert(num);
```